# How to create a grid or table in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanna create the same grid like the one in this picture to my view and paint it with different colors according to the date it represents. Does anybody know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: You could make a 2D array of UIViews and set their background color..

Comment: @Razvan How would that be any different from using a collection view, for example?

Comment: @Razvan, I don't see anything wrong with what I proposed.  ..I mean, as long as the 2D array isn't thousands of views large.  I get it could be heavy, but what else would you propose?

Comment: @rmaddy I think the difference would be in the huge memory consumption because of loading all those hundreds of uiviews on screen and off screen and because the collection view can dequeue what isn't needed. I also believe that a collection view has some great optimizations behind the curtains because it's made for this kind of stuff. Not to mention is way easier to work with a collection view than handling hundreds of views yourself manually.

Comment: @joels I've upvoted the accepted answer. I think this should answer your question.

Comment: @Razvan I'm not saying that you should use a bunch of views over using a collection view. But keep in mind, A collection view with 200 visible items will be showing 200 little views. No different than if you simply created the same 200 views without the collection view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` achieves this almost out of the box.